# How to use laravel components inside livewire lazy placholder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'd like to add skeleton from my laravel component inside livewire 3 placeholder
What i've tried so far :

Livewire class by including the laravel component :

```
public function placeholder()
{
    return <<<'HTML'
        <x-skeleton />
    HTML;
}
```

the above method renders nothing,

However when i tried to using direct HTML like these :

```
public function placeholder()

    {
        return <<<'HTML'
            <div class="card" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text placeholder-glow">
                        <span class="placeholder col-12"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text placeholder-glow">
                        <span class="placeholder col-12"></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        HTML;
    }
```

It works perfectly,
I prefer using the laravel components because its reusability
So how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lazy#default-placeholder-view) you can define a view in your config. So, you can create a view that renders your component, then set it in the config. This also saves you having to define the same placeholder on each component.

But, by the looks of things you can pass in any string, so you can also just return a rendered view: `view('view')->render()`. Again, same as before, you can just define a view where you render your component in.

Comment: this works well for me :)
but now i'm just curious why it didn't work inside the placeholder method tho

Comment: @owf Because you're returning a string. When you instead call `view('view')`, you're calling on the Laravel view factory, which will construct the view and also handle any includes, components, etc. The `render` method is just to build the view and return the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to make it simple. Can you make Livewire component's view on  conditional rendering.

Example :

In your Livewire component

```php
public $show_skeleton = true;
```

In your Livewire component's view

```html
<div>
    @if ($show_skeleton)
        <x-skeleton />
    @endif
</div>
```

In your Livewire component class

```php
public function showSkeleton()
{
    $this->show_skeleton = true;
}

public function hideSkeleton()
{
    $this->show_skeleton = false;
}
```

Now use this above method to show and hide your skeleton.

Comment: the problem seems not the method of how to trigger the skeleton to pop up,
its more about the component which can't be used inside on livewire's placeholder

Comment: ok my bad... just tried to help you